# Python: dict comprehensions: making a new dictionary with new values from old dictionary ids

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a simple dictionary. I am trying to create a new dictionary with the ids from the old dictionary and the lengths of the values from the old dictionary as values for the new dictionary. I have spent an hour on stack overflow trying find my answer but nothing has worked for me. I've tried some of the examples on the PEP 274 python page on the subject here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/ as well.

Here is what I am trying (python 2.7):

```
for k, v in old_dict.iteritems():
    new_dict = { k : len(v) for k in old_dict.keys() for v in old_dict.values()}
```

this gives me a nice new dictionary with the old dictionary's ids, but the value field is the same across all ids. For example:

```
old_dict = {'a':'andkfndknskfn', 'b':'nadfnn', 'c':'fn'}
```

with my code above I get:

```
new_dict = {'a':13, 'b':13, 'c':13}
```

what I want is:

```
new_dict = {'a':13, 'b':6, 'c': 2}
```

I beg you take pity on me :) I really did try for quite a while to find the answer myself but I am simply not successful. Thank you in advance for helping me find what I'm sure is a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the dictionary comprehension and the `for` loop, which both do more or less the same thing.  Just do this:

```
new_dict = { k: len(v) for k, v in old_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I do this, I get the following error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack". The value field is quite long - biggest is about 4k in length

Comment: @LaurenIntagliata: I just tried it using the sample data you gave in the question and it works.  Can you reproduce the error with a small sample of data?

Comment: No, I'm just an idiot. I changed the code in the dictionary call but still kept it in the loop. Thank you, this worked perfectly!