# New from old dictionary with combination of specific values with appropriate keys

Tags: python, dictionary

In this example, I have a dictionary of the form:

```
d = {1: {'z': 1, 'x': 11, 'y': 101},
     2: {'z': 2, 'x': 12, 'y': 102},
     3: {'z': 3, 'x': 13, 'y': 103}}
```

Note:In realty the integer values of `z`, `x`, and `y` are lists or arrays.

The intention is to (possibly with itertools) combine all the `z` values and form a new dictionary of the form:

```
new_dict = {12: {'p':(z1 + z2)},
            13: {'p':(z1 + z3)},
            23: {'p':(z2 + z3}}}
```

Here, `z1` corresponds to sub-dictionary `1` with value `z`,
`z2` corresponds to sub-dictionary `2` with value `z`,
`z3` corresponds to sub-dictionary `3` with value `z`.

---

My attempt:
I based my idea on extracting the values to first form a list. I an then form the combinations `c` from this list and populate a new dictionary with them.

```
# form list of values.
new_dict = {}
new_list = []
for k in d:
    new_list.append(d[k]['z'])

# populate new dictionary.
for n, c in enumerate(itertools.combinations(new_list, 2)):
    new_dict[n] = sum(c)
```

This gives me:

```
new_dict = {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}
```

I would then want to rename the keys (`mydict[new_key] = mydict.pop(old_key)`) to correspond to the appropriate combinations. In order to later append new information, I would also need to save the information as a sub-dictionary.

```
final_dict = {12: {'p':3}, 
              13: {'p':4},
              23: {'p':5}}
```

This is so I can easily track where the information has come from and later append new date to that combination. I'm not sure how I would do this in an iterative way to reflect where the data came from, or if this is the fastest/simplest route.

Note: I was unable to find an answer in [How to generate all combination from values in dict of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721847/how-to-generate-all-combination-from-values-in-dict-of-lists-in-python) or [Python: dict comprehensions: making a new dictionary with new values from old dictionary ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109777/python-dict-comprehensions-making-a-new-dictionary-with-new-values-from-old-di). Though they do provide ideas.

Comment: i see a bug in the code

Comment: Can you fix your sample `d`? Syntax is incorrect;

Comment: @Aditya thank you - should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to achieve your goal:

```
from itertools import combinations

d = {1: {'z': 1, 'x': 11, 'y': 101},
     2: {'z': 2, 'x': 12, 'y': 102},
     3: {'z': 3, 'x': 13, 'y': 103}}

new_dict = {}
for d1, d2 in combinations(d, 2):
    new_dict[int(str(d1) + str(d2))] = {'p': d[d1]['z'] + d[d2]['z']}

print(new_dict)
```

```
{12: {'p': 3}, 13: {'p': 4}, 23: {'p': 5}}
```